# Is there a RoboHelp alternative that generates XAML?

Tags: silverlight, xaml

Looking to generate help content for a number of Silverlight applications. Would like the content to be consumed directly inside Silverlight WITHOUT any browser interop as we want to support online & offline with minimal effort.

Comment: what the help content is exactly like ?? means what you wanna do like do you want a resource to be created or read from xml or feed in server ? Please illustrate . If a resource meant for a number of application then it needs to returned from a service. or a resource dictionary but has to be applied from the cs as it will be fetched from the service

Answer (score 1):

If your silverlight app uses a database, I would use the database to store your help topics.  This takes a little work but it is very flexible and cheap!

If you dont use a database, you can write it as XML (or other format if you prefer) and make it a resource in your application.  Then you can ready it like data. [Resource Files in Silverlight](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296240%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)